# How to search a list for a pair of coordinates?

Tags: python, list, search

I have a list of lists containing some text data and numerical coordinates, as follows:

```
coords = [['1a', 'sp1', '1', '9'],
          ['1b', 'sp1', '3', '11'],
          ['1c', 'sp1', '6', '12'],
          ['2a', 'sp2', '1', '9'],
          ['2b', 'sp2', '1', '10'],
          ['2c', 'sp2', '3', '10'],
          ['2d', 'sp2', '4', '11'],
          ['2e', 'sp2', '5', '12'],
          ['2f', 'sp2', '6', '12'],
          ['3a', 'sp3', '4', '13'],
          ['3b', 'sp3', '5', '11'],
          ['3c', 'sp3', '8', '8'],
          ['4a', 'sp4', '4', '12'],
          ['4b', 'sp4', '6', '11'],
          ['4c', 'sp4', '7', '8'],
          ['5a', 'sp5', '8', '8'],
          ['5b', 'sp5', '7', '6'],
          ['5c', 'sp5', '8', '2'],
          ['6a', 'sp6', '8', '8'],
          ['6b', 'sp6', '7', '5'],
          ['6c', 'sp6', '8', '3']]
```

Given a pair of coordinates (x,y), I want to find the element in the list (which will be itself a list) corresponding to said pair of coordinates. So, for example, if I have x = 5 and y = 12, I would get `['2e', 'sp2', '5', '12']`.

I tried this:

```
x = 5
y = 12
print coords[(coords == str(x)) & (coords == str(y))]
```

but got an empty list.

I also tried this:

```
import numpy as np    
print np.where(coords == str(x)) and np.where(coords == str(y))
```

but could not make any sense of what it returned `((array([ 2,  7,  8, 12]), array([3, 3, 3, 3])))`.

Could anyone give me a hand?

Comment: `list` objects do *not work like `numpy.ndarray` objects*.

Comment: This I already understood. Any suggestion towards a working solution?

Comment: Loop over your list, check if `sub[-2] == x and sub[-1] == y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of list comprehension. Iterate through all the coordinate and see where x and y are equal.

```
coords = [['1a', 'sp1', '1', '9'], ['1b', 'sp1', '3', '11'], ['1c', 'sp1', '6', '12'], ['2a', 'sp2', '1', '9'], ['2b', 'sp2', '1', '10'], ['2c', 'sp2', '3', '10'], ['2d', 'sp2', '4', '11'], ['2e', 'sp2', '5', '12'], ['2f', 'sp2', '6', '12'], ['3a', 'sp3', '4', '13'], ['3b', 'sp3', '5', '11'], ['3c', 'sp3', '8', '8'], ['4a', 'sp4', '4', '12'], ['4b', 'sp4', '6', '11'], ['4c', 'sp4', '7', '8'], ['5a', 'sp5', '8', '8'], ['5b', 'sp5', '7', '6'], ['5c', 'sp5', '8', '2'], ['6a', 'sp6', '8', '8'], ['6b', 'sp6', '7', '5'], ['6c', 'sp6', '8', '3']]

x = 5
y = 12

answer = [cood for cood in coords if int(cood[2]) == x and int(cood[3]) == y]
print(answer)
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks *a lot*.

Answer (score 2):

For a general solution you can use dictionary comprehension,

```
x, y = 5, 12
print({tuple(coord[-2:]):coord for coord in coords}[str(x),str(y)])
```

Comment: Note that if there is more than one match in the list, this will return only the last one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a simple Python solution try using this

```
[coord for coord in coords if coord[2] == str(x) and coord[3] == str(y) ]
```

This does return you back `[['2e', 'sp2', '5', '12']]`

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish in your solution `print coords[(coords == str(x)) & (coords == str(y))]`. You need to iterate through the list to find which of the elements match your `(x, y)` coordinates.

Comment: Also a simple and straight solution. The program statement you pointed out in my question (print coords[(coords == str(x)) & (coords == str(y))]) is obviously in error (and that's why it returned me an empty list).

Answer (score 1):

You could use this non-numpy list comprehension:

```
>>> [[a,b,c,d] for (a,b,c,d) in coords if int(c) == x and int(d) == y]
[['2e', 'sp2', '5', '12']]
```

Using `numpy`, you should compare only the third and fourth column to `x` and `y`, not the entire row, and take those indices.

```
>>> arr = np.array(coords)
>>> arr[(arr[:,2] == str(x)) & (arr[:,3] == str(y))]
array([['2e', 'sp2', '5', '12']], dtype='|S3')
```

Comment: The non-numpy solution is also a good one, but it returns only the first list element (and there maybe duplicates).

Comment: @maurobio Why should it only return the first one? If there are multiple elements that match the pattern, it will return them all.

Comment: Sure, I apologize. I wrote my comment based only on the example you provided, before running your code.